# A problem with the way to display the NavigationView

Tags: ios, swiftui

Use only one NavigationView I did not repeat it

But it appears to me at first

[image]

I have data in the first tab Home

All files I didn't put NavigationView only these

Perhaps the problem is from the Tab View file, is there an error?

```
struct CustomTabView: View {

@State var selectedTap = "iconeTap2"
    var body: some View {
    
    ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .bottom)) {
        
        TabView(selection: $selectedTap) {
           
           Tap1Home()   //Here Frist Tab
                .tag("iconeTap2")
            
            Tap2Home()
                .tag("iconeTap3")
            
            Tap2Home()
                .tag("iconeTap4")
            
            Tap2Home()
                .tag("iconeTap5")
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
        
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
           
            ForEach(tabs, id: \.self) { image in
              
                TabButton(image: image, selectedTab: $selectedTap)
                
                if image != tabs.last {
                    
                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal,25)
        .padding(.vertical,5)
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
}
```

here I put NavigationView

```
struct Tap1Home: View {

var body: some View {
    
    
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Tap1Section1()
            // Section *** 2
            Tap1Section2()
            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationTitle("22")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You need to post more code, but somehow you are in a `ColumnNavigationViewStyle `. Also, you haven't actually asked a question. How do you want us to help?

Comment: Why ZStack, no tabitem, ? You loose the bottom of each view in the tabview. What is there in contentView or MainView. What is the Problem?

Comment: in the MainView Existing file Tabview (CustomTabView)Just call this file There is nothing else

Comment: The problem is when I run the application directly, the one in the picture shows the back button and I did not put it

Answer (score 0):

There is a hint on screenshot - some NavigationLink is activated inside view which have "Home" as navigationTitle. You may have used NavigationLink's init with 'isActive' property with its value set to true in Tap1Section1 or Tap1Section2.